# RegEx find pattern and igonore all white space

Tags: regex, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I would like to find the following For Next loop within a script file. I have tried the following regex but doesn't work. I cant figure out how to skip all the white spaces. The text in the middle of the For Next can vary as well.

RegEx...

```
/[fF]or [eE]ach.*[aA]s [lL]ist[iI]tem [iI]n .*\.[]tems\s*.*[nN]ext/
```

Seach for this...

```
For Each item As ListItem In CheckBoxList1.Items
   If item.Selected = True Then
       MyList.Add(item.Text)
   End If
Next
```

Comment: One thing to note, is that your regex is looking for  [sS]tring  and your code is declared as ListItem

Comment: Thanks for mentioning, i will edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If what is between For and Next can vary I think you are looking for:

```
/[fF]or[\S\s]*?[nN]ext/
```

This will match anything that looks like **For(anything at all until the next:)Next**

If matching more words as you describe I would use something like:

```
/[fF]or\s+?[eE]ach[\S\s]+?[aA]s\s+?[lL]ist[iI]tem\s+?[iI]n[\S\s]+?[iI]tems[\S\s]+?[nN]ext/
```

Let me know if you want a more detailed description of this, but your example in the comments below will not ensure the in between words are also there.

Comment: thanks.It worked great. [\S\s]*? this was the key to what is was looking for. i need to check a couple other words too. so here is the final.../[fF]or [eE]ach.*[aA]s [lL]ist[iI]tem [iI]n .*\.[]tems[\S\s]*?[nN]ext/ This could probably be enhnaced a little better but it works.

Comment: It will not work: It just searches For followed by only spaces and then followed by Next!

Comment: @Roberto `\s` matches spaces/tabs/newlines `\S` is the negation which matches anything not a space/tab/newline

Comment: Thanks, @Matthew, I didn't noticed it, anyway, it should be clearer to use `.*?`. It would be better like this `/[fF]or\s+.*?\s+[nN]ext/`

Comment: @tszoro I don't think your final matching is doing what you think it will exactly. If you are matching the in between words you may want something like what I will edit in again.

Comment: @tszoro Not quite: the \. will not match line breaks without setting an additional option (which is not always supported). For clarity on a general question like this I typically use the [\S\s]

Comment: @Roberto The previous comment was meant to be in response to you and not tszoro

Comment: @Matthew Here is my final working version /[fF]or[\S\s]*?[lL]ist[iI]tem[\S\s]*?\.[iI]tems[\S\s]*?[nN]ext/ There is probably several ways to do it, this works for me. I tested it at [RegExTesting](http://sqa.fyicenter.com/Online_Test_Tools/Test_Regular_Expression_Match_Pattern.php)

Answer (score 0):

`\s` will match whitespace:

```
/[fF]or\s+[eE]ach.*[aA]s\s+[sS]tring\s+[iI]n\s+.*\.[]tems\s*.*[nN]ext/
```

Comment: How about the white space before 'Next'?

Answer (score 0):

I think this one will do it:
`/[fF]or\s+[eE]ach.*?[aA]s\s+[sS]tring\s+[iI]n\s+.*?\.[]tems\s+.*?\s+[nN]ext/`
remember `.*?` will match the shortest string possible.